# How to pass networkImageView using Intent to other activity in android

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

I am making a custom listview with image and some text. I have used this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/.Now I want to select a row item from listview and wants to display on other activity.I use onClickListener for this and pass data using Intent.But on other activity nothing is displaying.

This is my CustomListAdapter Class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import java.util.List;

import aquib.lathesis.volleylistview.R;
import aquib.lathesis.volleylistview.SingleItemView;
import aquib.lathesis.volleylistview.app.AppController;
import aquib.lathesis.volleylistview.model.Movie;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView item_image = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        TextView item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        TextView item_category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_category);
        TextView item_serve = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_serve);
        TextView item_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        item_image.setImageUrl(m.getItem_image(), imageLoader);

        // item name
        item_name.setText(m.getItem_name());

        // item category
        item_category.setText(m.getItem_category());

        // item serve
        item_serve.setText(m.getItem_serve());

       // item price
        item_price.setText(String.valueOf(m.getItem_price()));
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Movie p = movieItems.get(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), SingleItemView.class);
                i.putExtra("itemimage", p.getItem_image());
                i.putExtra("itemname", p.getItem_name());
                i.putExtra("itemcategory", p.getItem_category());
                i.putExtra("itemserve", p.getItem_serve());
                i.putExtra("itemprice",String.valueOf(p.getItem_price()));
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                activity.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
       return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is my SingleItemView Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import aquib.lathesis.volleylistview.app.AppController;
import aquib.lathesis.volleylistview.model.Movie;

public class SingleItemView extends Activity{

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    private static String TAG;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Get the view from singlelistview.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.singlelistview);


        try{
            Intent i = getIntent();
            //Get the result of item image
            i.getStringExtra("itemimage");
            //Get the result of item name
            i.getStringExtra("itemname");
            //Get the result of item category
            i.getStringExtra("itemcategory");
            //Get the result of item serve
            i.getStringExtra("itemserve");
            //Get the result of item price
            i.getStringExtra("itemprice");

            //Locate the image view
            NetworkImageView itemImage = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
            //Locate the text view
            TextView itemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            TextView itemCategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemCategory);
            TextView itemServe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemServe);
            TextView itemPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);

            Movie m = new Movie();

            itemImage.setImageUrl(m.getItem_image(), imageLoader);
            itemName.setText(m.getItem_name());
            itemCategory.setText(m.getItem_category());
            itemServe.setText(m.getItem_serve());
            itemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(m.getItem_price()));

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Data File

package aquib.lathesis.volleylistview.model;

```
public class Movie {
    private String item_image, item_name, item_category, item_serve;

    private double item_price;

    public Movie(){

    }

    public Movie(String item_image, String item_name, String item_category, String item_serve, double item_price) {
        this.item_image = item_image;
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.item_category = item_category;
        this.item_serve = item_serve;
        this.item_price = item_price;
    }

    public String getItem_image() {
        return item_image;
    }

    public void setItem_image(String item_image) {
        this.item_image = item_image;
    }

    public String getItem_name() {
        return item_name;
    }

    public void setItem_name(String item_name) {
        this.item_name = item_name;
    }

    public String getItem_category() {
        return item_category;
    }

    public void setItem_category(String item_category) {
        this.item_category = item_category;
    }

    public String getItem_serve() {
        return item_serve;
    }

    public void setItem_serve(String item_serve) {
        this.item_serve = item_serve;
    }

    public double getItem_price() {
        return item_price;
    }

    public void setItem_price(double item_price) {
        this.item_price = item_price;
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity File

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import aquib.lathesis.volleylistview.adapter.CustomListAdapter;
import aquib.lathesis.volleylistview.app.AppController;
import aquib.lathesis.volleylistview.model.Movie;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://labs.kamkazi.com/aquib/buenomobileapp/jsonparseitems.txt";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();

                                movie.setItem_image(obj.getString("item_image"));
                                movie.setItem_name(obj.getString("item_name"));

                                movie.setItem_category(obj.getString("item_category"));
                                movie.setItem_serve(obj.getString("item_serve"));
                                movie.setItem_price(((Number) obj.get("item_price"))
                                        .doubleValue());

                                 // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

These are Layout Files

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" >

        </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <!-- Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_image"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Category -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_category"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_image"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Serve -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_serve"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_category"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_image"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />

    <!-- Price-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

singlelistview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

    <!-- Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemImage"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Category -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemCategory"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/itemName"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemImage"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Serve -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemServe"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/itemCategory"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemImage"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />

    <!-- Price-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run my app first activity is displaying whole listview nice.But when I click on a row and open other activity then nothing is displaying except price view.And price text view is also not displaying properly.Please help me..

Comment: you need to create Movie instance with values from Intent not empty ...

Comment: @Selvin, Please tell me how?

Comment: ... or use directly values from intent ... you are calling `i.getStringExtra("itemprice");` but you do not store(nor use) this value anywhere ... you should pass those valuest not `m.getItem_price()` ...

Comment: Try to post relevent code instead of posting the complete project code in SO...Just show what you have tried for the particular functionalty..

Comment: @Selvin, Thanks bro.I fixed my issue..Now the problem is that imageview has covered the text view.Initially text view are displaying and then image view cover those views..Please help..